# linking failed when building a library

Tags: linker, makefile, configure

I am compiling and installing SDL_TTF from source to get the latest version used for development use.

I've already built and installed sdl2, sdl_image but this sdl_ttf is giving me some trouble.

when I from my build directory call

```
../configure -prefix=/opt/sdl2_ttf && make && make install
```

things seem to be going smoothly until I get down to linking what appears to be **glfont**.

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:504: recipe for target 'glfont' failed
make: *** [glfont] Error 1
```

I don't understand why this file wouldn't build.

Comment: The linker is saying that `libGL` does not exist in any of the directories
in its default search path. Either `libGL` is not installed or it is
installed somewhere the linker isn't looking. Do you think otherwise?

Comment: looking around there is GL.h in /usr/include/GL/ There's actually quite a few headers in there glcorearb.h  glext.h  gl.h  gl_mangle.h  glxext.h  glx.h  glx_mangle.h and an internal directory. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: A header file is not a library. What is the output of `find /usr/lib -name 'libGL*'`?

Comment: thank you, I was able to find out what's wrong. I am using linux now after migrating from mostly using terminal in os x. The problem stems from the fact that linux is case sensitive while mac os x is not. I didn't know that but now I do. The command that you provided show that the files were indeed there though, thanks for the help.